# "hg commit" - nothing happens!

Tags: mercurial

I just started my first Mercurial project.

I did a 'cd' into my source directory.

Then I did this:

```
hg init myproject
```

But next I did

```
hg commit -m "first commit"
```

And all it reports is:

```
nothing changed
```

But when I do

```
hg status
```

It lists all of the source code in my project.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, were you trying to follow along with this section of "Mercurial: The Definitive Guide": http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-the-basics.html#id349357 ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think the output of the `hg status` command is probably telling you that you have a lot of files in your working directory that are not being tracked by Mercurial.  You should be able to fix this by running the command

```
hg addremove
```

Then you can make your first commit:

```
hg commit -m "first commit"
```

Alternatively, you can do this all in one command with

```
hg commit -A -m "first commit"
```

Comment: 'hg addremove' is easier to use as the project grows.

Comment: 'hg addremove' is probably a better choice in this case, too, so I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: also 'commit -A' does an automatic add/remove.

Comment: What does `addremove` do? is it the same as `add`, then `remove -A`?

Answer (score -1):

Try `hg push` then refresh the  repository some times It changes inspite of saying nothing changed